# Application Loader ITMS 9000

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I try to upload my iOS application to the app store using application loader I get the following errors:

```
1. Apple's web service operation was not succesful

2. Unable to authenticate the package: 717608008.itmsp

3. ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx' for executable 'Payload/xxxxxxx.app/file name'."" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

I have tried the following to solve this issue:

- Used application loader to upload to the app store. I have also used the "default" upload tool built into Xcode (the one located in the Organizer window that open up after every archive).
- Solved other issues in the project that Xcode would alert about (I had problems with errors regarding icons, I solved this by setting "compress PNG icons" to NO in the Built Settings).
- Made sure the bundle ID for the project matched the one in the app store provisioning profile and app ID.
- Created a new app store provisioning profile in iTunes Connect, and afterwards refreshed all certificates in Xcode to make sure the changes took effect.
- Only Game Center and In App Purchase are enabled.
- Older build's that I have already uploadet to the app store produce the same error.
- When using the Application Loader, I have opened the activity window, which shows that the errors happen in the last step in the upload progress = It is when authenticating assets with the itunes store the errors happen.
- The errors also show up in Xcode 5.0.1
- Solutions on various forums have proven unsuccesful

I've spent about a week on this error total, and this update I'm trying to get out is quite important. A fast and helpful answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: In my case Using Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7 I was able to successfully upload by removing the `armv6` architecture from the target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload)