# Getting ITMS-4238 "Redundant Binary Upload" error no mater what I change the build version or app version to

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode6

I rejected a binary i had which was 1.0 (1.0).
The status went into Rejected by developer.

I went to upload a new binary and ran into this issue, i then saw that i needed to increment my build.

I increased both the app version and build to 1.1, this was a mistake.

I got some error about the app version not matching, understood.

Then i tried app version 1.0 and many different build numbers.
1.1, 1.0.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.0.3..nothing works.
I keep getting this error. There is only one build listed on itunes connect (1.0)

I tried submitting with no binary and it says i need one.

I even tried changing the app version to 1.1 in itunes connected and then uploading
1.1 (1.0) and that fails as well with the same duplicate issue.

Anyone ever have this issue?

[image: Screenshot for error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload

Comment: In addition to the answers below, don't forget you need to create a new archive, then select it in the organizer otherwise the build number change won't make any difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was trying for hours with no luck, after waiting a few more hours i got a reply from apple support asking for more info.
When i went to replicate the issue again for screenshots i decided to use a build number of 2.0, i was hoping maybe it wanted the major version to be higher.
This worked!
Everywhere online that i read said that 1.0 to 1.1 would work fine...or 1.0.0 to 1.0.1.
I, for some reason, had to go from 1.0 to 2.0.

Or there is always the possibility that waiting a few more hours did something.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my day! I was trying to upload an update. Old version 1.0 (build 1.0) new version 1.1. I tried setup build to 1.0.1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.0, 1.2, but the error was always the same! I set it to **2.0** and it worked! So, next time I would like to set 3.0... Thanks!! PS: mark your own answer as right answer.

Comment: But doesn't make sense if you're particular with your versioning convention. How about if I just wanted to replace the same build with a mistaken (or a not so updated) binary or something.  Is there no way to overwrite or remove the prevous build/s?

Comment: @crt79 Thanks for your answer. In my case, increasing the build number by minor number (like 1.2.1 to 1.2.2) also works :). Cheers

Comment: For anyone finding a problem with this using phonegap build.. change the version number in your iOS app in iTunes Connect and change the line in your config.xml: `<widget id="com.myapp.name" version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">` to the same version number. In this case: 3.0.0 respectively.

Answer (score 61):

The workaround of changing the build number is working for me, with the following context:

- the app version status is "Prepare for submission"
- the new version number is well saved in iTunesConnect (pressing the save button on version page in iTunesConnect)
- the CFBundleShortVersionString is matching the version number in iTunesConnect (e.g. "1.2")
- the CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist is incremented (e.g. 1.2.1)

In this way, several build are associated to the iTunesConnect version.

Here is how it looks like in iTunesConnect (1.2 is the short version number, 1.2 and 1.2.1 are the bundle versions):
[image]

Comment: Worked for me. You can also do that in Xcode, clicking on Project's root > Main Target > General and modifying the "Build" field (1.2.1), but not the "Version" field (1.2). Thanks

Comment: This seems like it would have worked for me but I ran into another issue: "The key CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version"  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error).

Comment: This method worked well for me. The key, though, was being patient in waiting for iTunes Connect to update after successful binary upload from Xcode. It took about 10 minutes from the notification of successful upload to the appearance of the new build in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 10):

Solved this issue by **incrementing build version by 1 instead of sub-version**. i.e. 1.0 to 2.0 instead of 1.0 to 1.1

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this also, just increase the build number fixed it for me. I changed the build version to 1.0.1 and it worked. This can be found in the 'General' Tab in Xcode. Make sure you archive and validate again before submitting to App Store.

Answer (score 4):

You need not to change the version number ,just change the Build number. But you should know that the Build number must be higher than last version you had uploaded. For example, your version number is `2.6.8` and Build number is `2.6.8` then you can change the Build number to `2.6.9`. If you change the Build number to `2.6.8.0` it will occur a error say that `the Build number(2.6.8.0) must be higher than the exist one(2.6.8)` . So the key point is Build number.

@Jayprakash Dubey 
@Tenaciousd93

Answer (score 2):

Tried many different build numbers myself. The only option that worked for me was to give a 4 figures build number : 1.1.0.1 (1.1 being my app version number on iTunes Connect).

Hope it helps!

Comment: With 4 figures version number, I got this error when trying to submit a binary : This bundle is invalid - The value for key CFBundleVersion [1.2.0.1] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers.

Comment: @Etienne Your version number should stay at 1.1 for instance, and you should use the 4-figures number only for the build number (1.1.0.1 in this example).

Answer (score 2):

I guess, since Apple has integrated test flight into itunesconnect, there is a difference between version and Build (which is the wording they use in project-settings->target->generalScreen) and in info.plist its equivalent is "Bundle Version String short" and "Bundle Version". Here the wording has never made real sense to me.

I have gotten the error with version 2.2 and build 2.2. I changed it to version 2.2 and build 1 (because it was my first upload) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For certain reason, Apple provided the build field on the General Tab in Xcode.

I have also encountered this issue and as much as you do, I am getting the same error over and over again even if I was changing the version numbers.

What is suppose to be done here is to update the build number only even using the same version number.

In my case, I have an App version 0.0.1, every time I upload a binary I need to change the build number eg: 
Upload build 0.0.0 - Reject Binary and 
Upload build 0.0.1 - Reject Binary and
Upload build 0.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I tried ApplicationLoader 2.9.1, it's working for me.
ApplicationLoader 2.9.1 can download from itunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and have solved it like you have, by upping my build number every time. It has always worked.

Now however, I am completely stuck. I have just added the Today Extension to my app, and now when I try to upload it always comes back with a 4238, no matter what version / build combination I put in. It's crazy, been at it for 2 hours now.

I'm wondering if there is any way certain build settings could make the uploader think there are 2 binaries?

I have a separate distribution profile for the main app and the extension, I also have 'Build Active Architectures Only' set to NO. That is all I can think of that would mess this up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It does not answer, you have to put it as a separate question or as a comment to some question.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the build number that I was updating in the General tab of Xcode wasn't changing the bundle version in the app's plist - so the uploader thought I was uploading the same build every time no matter what build number I was using. Once I changed the bundle version in the plist, everything worked fine.

Comment: After changing the build number it works fine Thanks for Your Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved same problem...I uploaded a version 1.01 and build 1.1 then I decided to reject this compilation. I Changed on i-tunes version to 1.1 and tried to upload new version 1.1 build 1.1 and I got error. Then I change on xcode to build 1.2 and upload ok.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to make build numer higher that last build number I uploaded. I had on iTunes Connect app with build number 3, then rewrote app from scratch and tried to upload new app with build number 1 I got same error, after changing to build number 4 it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have used the run script:
[image]

if the answer is yes, then you have to submit your changes to your git server, then the script will increase your build version number automatically!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by **Modifying** the **Build** Number under **General -> Identity** in the Target build of the Xcode project. Afterwards go to the Product menu, select **Clean** and **Build** your app.

```
From Build : 1
To Build   : 1.2
```

Finally, repeat the app submission process by running **Product** -> **Archive** and follow the screen prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the app, but for missing screenshots for 3.5", I got the same error.
And could not upload again from xcode.

(So I make an ipa file, in xcode organizer and export as ipa). 
But when I press the upload build in the itunesconnect then it take the old uploaded file (give me an option to choose). 
And then after saving this, I got the option for submit for review.

(If you go to the pre release tab in itunesconnect, you can see the previously uploaded app.)