# Trubleshooting xcode Upload Issues

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

What do i do if this pops up? ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0.1' for train '1.0'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25981890/1531971

Comment: yeah, duplicate.