# Confusing message from itunes connect regarding app status?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, phonegap-build

I currently have an app that has a 'Waiting for review' status.

I had a email saying....

```
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Cavorts". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Redundant Binary Upload - There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.4' for train '1.4'

Invalid Pre-Release Train - The train version '1.4' is closed for new build submissions

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
```

BUT the status of the app is still 'Waiting for review' - in the past it would change to 'Binary rejected' but im not sure now if its still waiting or do I need to address this issue.

Im guessing to fix it I'd have to remove the 1.4 version and re package a 1.4.1 version anad upload that.

Comment: I am getting same Email. Any idea what I have to do now?

Comment: I removed the 1.4 version and added a 1.4.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you upload new binary, you have to increase the build number. Other wise itunes does not allow the binary. For more details you can refer the following link. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload)

Comment: The last version (thats currently in the store) was 1.3. Nothing has been uploaded since then so I dont understand where the 1.4 issue comes from. But either way it doesnt explain why its telling me to upload a new binary while itunes connect says its in review? Thanks.

Comment: No need to remove manually, you try with the new updated version.