# Version number not updating when archiving in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

This is what the version & build number show up as inside of xCode.

[image: Version & build inside xcode]

After archiving the version number appears to remain the same as the previous one.

[image: Version & build after archiving]

Error message I am getting after trying to upload the application

[image: Error Message]

Has anybody had this problem before or can you think of any possible fixes?

Comment: Version and build numbers do not automatically update after an archive. If you want to achieve that, you need to your own script or other implementation.

Comment: @siburb so if I change the version number in xcode, and product > archive, the number shown in the archive should not reflect the updated number that I changed manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload)

Comment: @Baker2795 : getting same issue for me, any info on this will be helpful. Even if I manually update the build and version number, after archiving previous version and build number was displaying. Is this any cache issue. please help

Comment: @Baker2795 did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

CFBundleShortVersionString CFBundleVersion Please check these two values in your info.plist file, you must have hard coded them sometime. It was the case with me. These values were hard codedly given