# iOS app build not showing up in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I know there are a lot of questions about this already, but I am fairly certain my question has not been answered yet.

I uploaded a build of my iOS app via Application Loader, and that went well. I got to the end with a message of "Done", so I thought it was okay.

Then I went to check in iTunes Connect and I cannot see a build (**not even under "Activity"**). I waited for an hour and I retried uploading the build. In Application Loader I now get the error "Redundant Binary Upload", so that tells me that my build is somewhere in iTunes Connect, but I can't find it.

What could have gone wrong? Is this something that usually happens? How can I know when my build is "Processing", so I can continue with the release process?

Comment: how much time before you have deployed the build on itunes.

Comment: This is already answered .Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload)

Comment: just need to be patient, this sometimes takes a couple of hours.

Comment: @dirtydanee even for the app to even show up under "Activity" as "Processing"?

Comment: yes, if this is the first build you submit, it can take a while.

Comment: @vrwim are you add all Privacy -  Description key in your plist ?

Comment: @balkaransingh I don't know what you mean

Comment: like for clander we add  Privacy - Calendars Usage Description in .plist .

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html in my case when i add the key description of photos and location it's work for me.

Comment: @vrwim have you received any mail ?

Comment: TestFlight had errors yesterday, and appears to be having errors now as well--I am experiencing problems uploading similar to those I received yesterday. The Apple system status page does not report any problems with TestFlight, so this may be a localized issue, but if it is a problem with TestFlight, the only remedy is to wait for Apple to fix.

Answer (score 14):

If you have the email of developer account apple search emails. If you up to itunesconnect an ipa and you can´t see in 5 min Apple always send a mail with the problem some times bad missing icons on app, problems like "privacy-sensitive data without a usage description" or with push notifications disabled ... You must fix the problem, increase the build version and upload again.

Here an example:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please be patient as it takes some time to process your build and show up on iTunes. Try checking the "**Build**" section from where you'll select the build in order to proceed and submit for review.

Answer (score 0):

Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key

For older projects without assets catalog there will be issues while submitting to Appstore

**In Project —> Target Properties - General tab—> App Icons and Launch Image. App Icons —> Select Use Asset catalog** Then it will ask to convert (migrate) with an alert and creates a .xcassets file. Check the box to convert launch images too.
When you are done the App Icons Source and the Launch Images Source will have names in the dropdown list. Add the app icons and other icons to it

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Appstore and I was facing the same issue. I have just increased the build version and uploaded a new build on Appstore. New uploaded build start showing in the activity tab.