# Apple TestFlight not showing compilations

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, apple-developer

I´m trying to test my app, but in the iOS tab, it shows me the versions but none inside it (see image). Is it normal?
I can´t find a way to test it.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the email of developer account apple search emails. If you up to itunesconnect an ipa and you can´t see in 5 min Apple always send a mail with the problem some times bad missing icons on app problems with push notifications disabled ...
Is the same issue than this reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40246412/4693765

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a build will simply get lost, never appear for processing.

Sometimes it will be just one build, sending in another will work (don't forget to increment the build number).

On one occasion, the actual queue of builds seemed stuck, I had to ask them for help, and the fixed it, but didn't provide an explanation.

In these cases, I did not get any error messages or email, but I did notice that the email-notification never was sent to me.