# swift ios - Build is not showing on itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded my ios app to app store but itunes connect build is empty. What seem to be the problem? Thanks

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Click the `Activity` tab. Perhaps your build is not done processing yet.

Comment: is says All builds that have been submitted for iOS. Version numbers are the Xcode version numbers. its empty

Comment: Is it possible that you are looking at the wrong app, or your upload did not actually complete as you thought it did?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook how do i know that build is not done processing yet?

Comment: A build that has not finished processing will show up under `Activity`, be grayed out, and say `(Processing)`

Comment: i have not seen that in my itunes connect

Comment: There is none actually , what seem to be the problem if the build does not appear but submission to app store was successfull

Comment: Facing same problem. Have you found why your build is missing?

Comment: Hi, check your e-mails and watch out for mails like "Your app [...] has one or more issues". If there are missing plist-keys or icons, itunesconnect will send you this errors by mail.

Comment: Please have look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751681/2692839)