# Build Not visible in iTunes connect after uploading successfully

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, ipa, application-loader

I am facing issue related to app uploading to iTunes connect, I have uploaded my application build to iTunes connect it is showing successfully uploading but on iTunes connect in Activity section it is showing processing for some time after some time passed when I am trying to reload page then build is missing from there.Then after again if i upload build then it is showing redundant binary upload.Also tried with different build number then also happening same its initially shows processing but removed from Activity section later.

I have already set all privacy policy descriptions in info.plist as well.What other thing i am missing can anyone tell?

Comment: your build probably got rejected . please check your email for details

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751681/2692839)

Answer (score 6):

**The build is not visible until the "Processing" step is in progress in the "Prerelease" tab. It should depend on the size of your app. For a 20Mb app of mine, it took about 15 min.**

---

If it is not shown then Check your inbox for an email from iTunes Store:

Subject: iTunes Connect: Your app [...] has one or more issues

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for [your app]. To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

[...]

Once the required corrections have been made, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

**XCode 9 told me the upload was successful, but the build did not appear in iTunesConnect until I fixed the issues indicated in the email and resubmitted.**